# Замена одного значения на другое в строке

Tags: php

Есть исходная строка `Тип_разъема=AM4&Количество_ядер=4`, в которой необходимо заменить `AM4` и `4` на `'AM4'` и `'4'` соответственно.

```
$explode = explode("&", $translate);
foreach ($explode as $key)
{
    $s = explode("=", $key);
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($s as $k)
    {
        if($i % 2 == 1)
        {
            // echo $s[$t];
            $translate = str_replace($k, "'".$k."'", $translate);
        }
        $i++;
        // if($i == 2)
        // {
        //  $translate = str_replace($k, "'".$k."'", $translate);
        // }
    }
}
```

Но в итоге получается вот это: `Тип_разъема='AM'4''&Количество_ядер='4'`. Со строкой, в которой нет повторяющихся чисел, все нормально работает. Пробовал сделать какой-то лимит для `str_replace`, но все равно ничего не выходит. Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: после того, как написал сюда, появилась идея как это можно исправить и исправил, теперь все хорошо работает. К сожалению,я не знаю как удалить тему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то могу предложить такое, не самое красивое, но работающее решение.

```php
<?php
$text = "Тип_разъема=AM4&Количество_ядер=4";
$text = str_replace("=" ,"='" , $text);
$text = str_replace("&" ,"'&" , $text);
$text =  $text."'";
echo $text;
//Выводит 
//Тип_разъема='AM4'&Количество_ядер='4'
?>
```

Comment: Я, пытаясь это сделать, намудрил много лишнего, когда можно было сделать таким способом. Спасибо!

Comment: Вы можете принять ответ, нажав на галочку рядом с ответом.

Answer (score 0):

Александр Анашкин, изучайте синтаксис регулярных выражений.

```
$text = 'Тип_разъема=AM4&Количество_ядер=4';
echo preg_replace('~(?<==)|(?=&|$)~', '\'', $text);
```

Comment: @Александр Анашкин, запостил ответ.